# Application in VB does not run after opening url in webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am using the webbrowser.navigate ("url of my application") after I open my interface in C#, the search part is in VB and is not loaded, the error display is that the communication time has run out.

```
public override DataSet Search(DataSet d)
{
    try
    {
        WSConection.WS.DataRet ret = wso.Search(pDts);  //Stop here
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(ret.SchemaXML));
        ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(ret.DataXML));
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

em System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
em System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
em WSConection.WS.WS.Search(DataSet pDataForScript) na arquive.cs:linha 135
em WSConection.WSO.Search(DataSet pDts) na arquive.cs:linha 75
```

If I change my webbrowser url to google for example the search loads normal.

I ran the server application locally, search also works, how do I solve this? Seems to me to be cache.

Comment: show us the code where you got the error

Comment: Does it work if you enter the URL in an ordinary browser?

Comment: Yes, the url works on all browsers. @AndrewMorton